# SSMS Loses Connection To SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using SSMS 18.4 and I typically have a bunch of tabs open as I work.

A couple of times a week, my session in a tab or two will become disconnected.  Trying to reconnect it doesn't work.   No errors occur, it just doesn't connect.

Also New Queries start off as disconnected.   Hitting the connect button seems to work fine but the tab stays disconnected in the lower left of the coding pane.

The only way I can bring back functionality to these tabs is to completely close SSMS (which is a pain when your in the middle of coding.)

**Is there a trick or way to do connect tabs that are not connecting in the traditonal sense without closing out of SSMS?**

Comment: This is not normal behavior. Not related, but I suggest you upgrade to the current SSMS version as you are several releases behind.

Comment: Thanks. I just did that. I'll see if it helps.